# How do you backstab in Bloodborne?

Tags: bloodborne

I can't seem to figure out how to backstab in Bloodborne, it doesn't seem to be like in the previous Souls games, Can someone give me a bit of *insight* on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Bloodborne Wiki](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Backstab) (well, one of them) :

> Backstabs in Bloodborne can be performed by holding <kbd>R2</kbd> (**charging up your heavy attack**) and releasing it into the back of the enemy. The enemy will be briefly **staggered**, allowing you to position yourself directly **behind it** and press <kbd>R1</kbd>, performing the backstab.
>
> *This is a change form Souls games, where all that was needed was the <kbd>R1</kbd> attack behind the enemy.*
>
> You also can **chain backstabs**, to do so just charge your <kbd>R2</kbd> again as soon the previous backstab animation is over, by the time your target's standup-animation is done your second charged up R2 will hit and you are free to backstab again.